# RegEx in Javascript - valid time format

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following method to check time is in format `hh:mm`.

Now I also will allow negative time (`-hh:mm`).

I am not good in regex. Maybe someone can help me with the regular expression.

```
function isAmountOfTimeValid(amountOfTime) {
    var pattern = new RegExp('^\\d{1,3}(:\\d{1,2})?$')
    var result = pattern.test(amountOfTime);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Try: `var pattern = /^-?\d{1,2}(:\d{1,2})?$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
/^-?\d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2})?$/
```

It is very similar to OP regex, only added `-?` to optionally match a negative sign at string begin and substituted the capturing group by a non-capturing (`?:`), because nothing needs to be captured here.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eI8uL0/1)

---

```js
function isAmountOfTimeValid(amountOfTime) {
    var pattern = new RegExp('^-?\\d{1,2}(?::\\d{1,2})?$')
    var result = pattern.test(amountOfTime);
    return result;
}

var test_set = ["13:00", "-13:00", "13", "133:0"]

for(var i = 0; i < test_set.length; i++){
  alert(test_set[i] + ": " + isAmountOfTimeValid(test_set[i]))
}
```